VISUAL STUDIO: .net function app renders without build with coding errors (old version?)
I am building a .net function app;
Imagine this inside my startup class:

there is a clear coding error; and it is even displayed inside my error output:

(yservice doesnt exist).
However, I can hit build and run or and the solution, even flawed, will render.
I can also add files to it; and new endpoints; and they work fine.

Why is VS building the solution
What am I seeing? It cant be the flawed code, so it must be an old version of it: however; cleaning and rebuilding doesnt fix this.

Thank you

Are there multiple projects in the solution?  Perhaps the startup project doesn't use (and therefore doesn't build) the errant code shown?  Have you specifically selected "Rebuild Solution"?  Something else?

yes, there are; but i am deffinately building the function app inside the repo and the error is right within the startup file

also; i cannot hit REBUILD this will fail, i can only "RUN"

"i cannot hit REBUILD this will fail" - How will it fail?  With expected error(s) from the known errant code?  If you run in a debug session, can breakpoints in this code be hit?  Or is there some message when hovering over such breakpoints indicating that they won't be hit for some reason?

yes, it then fails with the expected errors; also yes, i can hit breakpoints just fine. however, if i have a coding error and add a breakpoint the breakpoint gets a little ! next to it, and it wont trigger

Even if the source code contains errors, an outdated DLL from a previous successful build might still be used during execution. This can happen if Visual Studio isn't correctly cleaning up and rebuilding the necessary files.Manually delete the bin and obj folders of your project, and then perform a clean rebuild (Build > Clean Solution, then Build > Rebuild Solution).
